# Angular 2 remove blank option and select the first option only

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have an array defined in typeScript file

```
 statusList: string[] = ['YES','NO']
```

Now I am iterating through the array in HTML page

```
 <select id='status' [(ngModel)]="model.truckStatus" name = "status" #status = "ngModel" required>
    <option *ngFor = "let status of statusList">
 </select>
```

When I load the page by default I am getting an empty option, how to make the first value from an array to be selected by default?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to add the following line to the component ngOnInit() method:

this.model.truckStatus = this.statusList[0];

And if the statusList is not defined in the component class, we should remove the this keyword and import the statusList array.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. In attribute condition, you can set any function and check some properties.

```
<select id='status' 
        [(ngModel)]="model.truckStatus" 
        name = "status" 
        #status = "ngModel" 
        required>

    <option *ngFor = "let status of statusList"
            [attr.selected]="status === 'YES'">
 </select>
```